# Windows Server 2012 and .NET FW 2.0: do they fit together?

Tags: winforms, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012

Do you know if Windows Server 2012 can run .NET Framework 2.0 applications?
So far I tried to install .NET framework 2.0 (for running an application that's based on this version) but it fails.

Microsoft website informs that WS 2012 includes .NET FW 4.5 or 4.5.1 but does not say about .NET 2.0

Do you know?
Thank you

Comment: Have you tried this guide? http://windowsitpro.com/windows-8/q-how-do-i-install-net-framework-35-30-and-20-windows-8

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does, but you have to install the feature.

Click the start button, type `Windows Features` and click `Turn Windows features on or off`. That should bring up the Server Manager and automatically after a second or two bring up the "Add Roles and Features Wizard." Click next until it gets to `Features`. Check the box at the top that says ".NET Framework 3.5 Features." This includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0.